# Combining two meta_values within one row with query

Tags: query, post-meta, user-meta, wp-user-query

I've added two new meta_keys to the `wp_usermeta` table:

`bid_user_lat` and `bid_user_lng`

And I need to be able to get both of these values within a single row, along with the `user_id`.

`ROW - (user_id) 220 | (bid_user_lat) 45.099080 | (bid_user_lng) -140.09099`

Now comes the tricky part ... I then need to use these values within a calculated radius statement:

`( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @lat ) ) * cos( radians( **bid_user_lat.meta_value** ) ) * cos( radians( **bid_user_lng.meta_value** ) - radians( @lng ) ) + sin( radians( @lat ) ) * sin( radians( **bid_user_lat.meta_value** ) ) ) )  AS distance`

In the end, I'm making sure that the user is within a certain radius, and if so, I will return it within the query.

**But the most important part is being able to query the `wp_usermeta` the way I need to!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `WP_User_Query` class which works much like `WP_Query`.

The docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Below is a dump of the WP_User object that it will return, in this example using:

```
$wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array( 'fields' => 'all_with_meta' ) );
$get_users = $wp_user_search->get_results();
```

[image: user var_dump]

This should set you in the right direction because it was not obvious how your new meta_keys are set up and exactly how you want to run the query. The second question isn't really related to WordPress :)

If you don't want to use `WP_User_Query` you will have to use `$wpdb` which is more direct mySQL query.

it would be something like:

```
global $wpdb;
$get_map_user = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'bid_user_lat'");
```

It would probably be better if you had one `meta_key` with 2 values for your long/lat, instead of 2 meta keys.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Thanks for responding! I've now combined the two meta_key entries into one serialized cell. But now I'm not sure how to extract the data from a serialized string ...

Comment: That is more a PHP question, you can use `unserialize` or a WordPress's function called  `maybe_unserialize` . It would be best to close this question and ask a new one with a specific example.